# SSL handshake failed: SSL error: Key usage violation in certificate has been detected

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ssl, visualsvn-server

I have installed kdesvn in ubuntu. But when I am trying to checkout, getting this error.

```
SSL handshake failed: SSL error: Key usage violation in certificate has been detected.
```

I have came across the solution for this as

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27.old
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libneon27
cd /usr/lib
sudo rm libneon-gnutls.so.27
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27
```

But Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: never mind.the second one is did the trick. But we need to restart the app after the change.

Comment: You can find the solution in VisualSVN KB at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00056/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CentOS 6 and SVN w/ Neon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189254/centos-6-and-svn-w-neon)

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install libneon27
cd /usr/lib
sudo rm libneon-gnutls.so.27
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27 (double check that symbolic link is created)
```

you may need to restart after that. 
Now when you do `svn checkout`, An option will come to trust the certificate permanently. Do that.

Comment: These commands works like a charm in my ubuntu 12.04.
Thank you.