# svn connection after OS re-install

Tags: svn, ssl-certificate

I had a folder which was version tracked using svn and it was working fine.

For other reasons, I had to change my OS from RHEL 5.4 to RHEL 6.6. So we took full backup of the folder, formatted the system and re-installed the new OS from scratch.

Now when I try to use svn, I get "SSL handshake failed: SSL error: Key usage violation in certificate has been detected." error.
On googling, it pointed to 
1. use libneon instead of libneon-gnutls ([SSL handshake failed: SSL error: Key usage violation in certificate has been detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998025))
- when I ls /usr/lib/libneon* I get no results. I guess it means I have neither of the libneon library. Should I try installing libneon? (dont have root access, hence would like re-confirm before going thru libneon installation approval process)
2. Reinstall self-signed certificate (https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00056/)
- Tried, it didnt work. Still same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly suggest ensuring that you've properly followed the instructions provided in the article [KB56: Сertificate key usage violation in Subversion clients built against GnuTLS](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00056/). Check that you've made the Windows Registry adjustments as described in the article. If you use VisualSVN Server and the problem you've encountered is the same as described in the article, these instructions will definitely help to workaround the problem.

Note that the workaround specified in the article is just a workaround and not a solution. The best solution would be to use the latest Subversion 1.9 client built with up-to-date OpenSSL version.